# Add formatted current date to file name

Tags: vb6

I want to zip a file using vb6.0 code. The following code isactually doing the zipping part.

How can I add the current date to the file name?

```
Sub ZipAFile(filename, filepath, Optional outputFileName, Optional outputfilepath)

    Dim d As String
    filename = ABC.xls
    filepath = App.Path & "\" & "New_Folder\"
    d = Date

    If Right(filepath, 1) <> "\" Then filepath = filepath & "\"
    If IsMissing(outputFileName) Then
        outputFileName = Left(filename, InStr(1, filename, ".") - 1) & ".zip"
    Else
        outputFileName = Trim(outputFileName) & ".ZIP"
    End If
    If IsMissing(outputfilepath) Then
        outputfilepath = filepath
    Else
        outputfilepath = Trim(outputfilepath)
        If Right(outputfilepath, 1) <> "\" Then outputfilepath = outputfilepath & "\"
    End If
    Shell "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe a """ & outputFileName & """ """ & outputfilepath

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean my system date? can you give an example?

Comment: "I want to add system date to the outputfilename. which is not happening" - why would you expect that to happen? If you want that, you need to add some logic to produce that outcome.

Comment: A little hard to understand what you want. You're assigning the date to a variable "d", but you never use it in the code sample. Did you mean to insert d into the output file name?

Comment: The above code give a zip file name ABC.zip, I wanted to make the zip file name as ABC 16/10/2014.zip  I tried like           outputFileName = Left(filename, InStr(1, filename, ".") - 1) & d & ".zip". But no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the format of the date however you see fit using the [`Format$`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa241719(v=vs.60).aspx) function:

```
Sub ZipAFile(filename, filepath, Optional outputFileName, Optional outputfilepath)

    Dim d As String
    filename = ABC.xls
    filepath = App.Path & "\" & "New_Folder\"
    d = Format$(Now, "yyyymmdd") '// Change date formatting here

    If Right(filepath, 1) <> "\" Then filepath = filepath & "\"
    If IsMissing(outputFileName) Then
        outputFileName = Left(filename, InStr(1, filename, ".") - 1) & d & ".zip" '// Append your date string
    Else
        outputFileName = Trim(outputFileName) & d & ".ZIP" '// Append your date string
    End If
    If IsMissing(outputfilepath) Then
        outputfilepath = filepath
    Else
        outputfilepath = Trim(outputfilepath)
        If Right(outputfilepath, 1) <> "\" Then outputfilepath = outputfilepath & "\"
    End If
    Shell "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe a """ & outputFileName & """ """ & outputfilepath

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create a zip file without third party software (in your case 7zip.) Just an FYI.

```
Sub zip_a_file(path_to_target As String, _
           file_with_extension_to_compress As String, _
           zip_file_path As String, _
           zip_file_name_without_extension As String)

Dim ZipFile
Dim o As Object
Dim d As String

'First, do a little bit of testing to see if the inputs are OK

If Right(path_to_target, 1) <> "\" Then
    path_to_target = path_to_target & "\"
End If

If Right(zip_file_path, 1) <> "\" Then
    zip_file_path = zip_file_path & "\"
End If

'Get the date and format it

d = Format(Now, "yyyymmdd")

'Create Empty Zip Package

ZipFile = zip_file_path & zip_file_name_without_extension & d & ".zip"
Open ZipFile For Output As #1
Print #1, Chr$(80) & Chr$(75) & Chr$(5) & Chr$(6) & String(18, 0)
Close #1

'Do some zippin'

Set o = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
o.Namespace(ZipFile).CopyHere (path_to_target & file_with_extension_to_compress)

'Clean up

Set o = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting idea. It would be safer to create the file using binary file writing rather than text file writing. For instance I think that code would fail on a PC with codepage set to a double-byte-character set e.g. Chinese.

Comment: More troublesome is the async nature of `CopyHere` and there is no way of detecting if the zip is complete or if the source files are needed anymore. Did I mention `CopyHere` displays a progress dialog with no option to disable it.

Comment: @wqw: Since the code above requires a shell process, and there is no good way to know how long it will take, it is a candidate for [shell-and-wait.](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ShellAndWait.aspx)

Comment: @tbur: It's already out-of-process i.e. `CopyHere` uses `explorer.exe` to perform the "copy" in background (async). There is no way to block on the operation that I'm aware of.

Comment: This is Mike Strong's idea from here: http://tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1302498 . There's an interesting discussion on the subject there, which will give some reasons why this is the way it is.